# Why are 5 IP addresses using my API key?

Tags: bug, apps

I have an app that resides on a server. It has only ever accessed the API from 2 IP addresses. The API key has *not* been shared and there is no client-side code.

When I go to /apps however, it says "5 unique visitors."

There's a bug in there somewhere.

Comment: The app is StackMobile, by the way.

Comment: your server is on a farm, no?

Comment: @code: No. It's a lone server.

Comment: Do you have a dynamic IP address?

Comment: No. It's a web server. Fixed address.

Answer (score 2):

That's 5 unique visitors since the key was registered.  You've never run tests or prototypes from not-the-production-server?

Comment: Oh... since it was registered... possibly. I'm not sure, but possible. I got the impression those numbers were just *recent* users.

Comment: @George - nope, they're "all time".